# creating weekly report in ruby on rails that cover empty date with 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a sale table, consist of 5 columns

```
id, sale_code, total_sale, created_at, updated_at
```

I want to make a weekly report like this

```
date       | total_sale
2016-09-27 |  1000
2016-09-28 |     0
2016-09-29 |   500
```

and when there is no product being sold that day, in the report still showed it with 0 value.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: When generating your table in the view you can just add some ruby code that substitutes 0 for any nil values...

Comment: the question is, when i have a data consist of 2016-09-27 and 2016-09-29, and also there is no selling in day 28, how to show it?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through each day of the current week and count all sales of the day.

It could look like something like that:

```
today = Date.today
week_days = (today.at_beginning_of_week..today.at_end_of_week).map
week_sales = Sales.where("created_at > ? AND created_at < ?", week_days.first.beginning_of_day, week_days.last.end_of_day)

p "date | total_sale"

week_days.each do |day|
  day_sales = week_sales.count{|sale| sale.created_at > day.beginning_of_day && sale.created_at < day.end_of_day}
  p "#{day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")} | #{day_sales}"
end
```